# Is it normal for my dsPIC to run warm?

Tags: pic, integrated-circuit

My dsPIC33FJ128GP706A is being powered by a PICkit 3 at 3.19V. I can program the chip perfectly - it is recognised by my programmer.

I felt it and it is quite warm. Not hot, just warm. I measured using my infra-red thermometer and it is at 37°C in a room which is around 23°C at the moment. Not anywhere near the limit, but I'm curious as to why it is getting warm. Is it normal? Or is there a problem on my board? (which is rather poorly soldered.)

The Vcore voltage measures at 2.58V, which is within the allowed tolerances. It's being powered from the dsPIC's on-board LDO.

Answer (score 5):

You have all the information, so do the math and you can answer the question yourself.

The PIC is at 37C and ambient is at 23C, for a rise of 14C.  The first knee jerk reaction is that this is quite reasonable.

Next you look in the datasheet and see what the thermal resistance to ambient is.  This is shown quite clearly in table 25-3 on page 272, right where you'd expect to find it.  It says the typical thermal resistance of the 64 pin TQFP package is 40 degC/Watt.  Since you see a 14C rise, that implies the chip is dissipating 350 mW.

Next you look again in the datasheet (do you see the recurring theme here?) and see how much power you should expect the part to dissipate.  Table 25.5 on page 274 show the power current at 3.3V and several operating frequencies.  The maximum is 90 mA at 40 MIPS, which is 297 mW.  That's a bit less than it is apparently dissipating, but the 297 mW value doesn't include any of the peripherals or extra dissipation due to I/O pin current.  Overall, the numbers look close enough and there is enough slop so that your observed temperature rise doesn't sound out of line.

Comment: Thanks for your calculations Olin. However, my processor has no code and is not clocked at the moment. I think it is being held in reset too but I'm not sure. So it does seem abnormal...

Comment: @Thomas - If you're not clocked and have no code running, it's hard to say what's happening.  Add a clock source (or program to use an internal oscillator), and program the PIC to change every port a high-impedance digital input, then put it into deep sleep (or while(1); depending on what you want to measure).  That should give you power data comparable with the numbers in the datasheet.

Answer (score 0):

By repeatedly reprogramming my dsPIC33FJ128GP802 SOIC I have managed to push it up to 15 Celcius.

- Ambient temperature: 19 Celcius.
- Running temperature (performing some hefty signal generation): 10 Celcius.
- Power supply: 3.3V

So yes, I would think there is possibly something up with your circuit.  You're not overclocking it are you?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds reasonably normal, but it would help to know what it's doing. For example is it sleeping or running at 40MIPS and toggling all it's pins?
The power difference between these two scenarios would be huge.
Just checked the datasheet and it says that it can pull ~20mA when idle at 40 MIPS. This is with clock on, core off and all modules turned off. If you have some loading on pins and the core is on then it seems like it could easily draw a lot more. If not idle, it says around 84mA, with all pins at Vss and peripherals off but clocked, driven from external clock.
 Easiest way to figure out if things are normal would be to program to a *known* state, check the current and compare with specs in datasheet.
Thermal rating range from 40C/W for all but the QFN package at 28C/W. You would be looking at drawing ~100mA @3.3V to raise the temperature this much.

Answer (score 0):

37° seems high, but still within normal range.  Are you powering external devices that require a lot of current directly from the PIC?  If so, I would suggest getting some MOSFETS or H-Bridges to control power to those devices.  Current draw on output is one of the biggest factors in pushing up the operating temperature.  LEDs are typically fine, but any kind of motor will cause problems.

Comment: I'm thinking there might be a short circuit on part of my board. The design doesn't require any more than a few mA from any pin. And this is without any program loaded yet.

Comment: Did you solder part of the board yourself?  If so, check that you haven't shorted one of your solder joints.